# Island camping tent advice

Tags: camping, tents, beach

I am planning on camping on the beach in Florida. Since I will be on an island I have to pack what I can carry. I do not have a tent yet, and was wondering what I should look for in a tent for a Florida Beach. Current temp here 80-90°F (27–32°C) with not much wind on average.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options. You could buy a 2-season tent, that would be light(er than a 4 season for sure) or a tent fly.

A tent fly would be ideal as it would be very light but I wouldn't use in some places where there are animals dangerous wandering around during the night.

A 2-season tent you can zip it up and sleep without the problem of snakes, scorpions or spiders coming to snuggle with you during the night.

Where I live, there are no animals to concern me, so I usually carry a fly from end spring to beginning fall and a tent the rest of the year. I only carry a full tent because of rain. I can also carry only my tent fly and poles, so if it's going to be windy but warm enough, I can shave some weight on that.

Please keep in mind my answer is more of a generic answer, I don't know Florida beaches but I come from a country with similar kind of weather.

Comment: to add on your answer, he should probably also get sand anchors?

Comment: @HTDutchy - True story... :) Sand anchors would be good. We can always improvise as well with rocks and things to avoid the extra weight, specially in beaches were it's easy to dig holes.